# WebClient in springboot servlet application gives StackOverflowError: null during startup

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, httpclient, netty, webclient

Multi-Module application containing both spring-boot-starter-web(in parent pom) and spring-boot-starter-webflux(in child pom) gives Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null for webClient used for Oauth2.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorResourceFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.RemoveAuthorizedClientOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider;
import reactor.netty.transport.ProxyProvider;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.UUID;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
public class OAuthWebClientConfig{
    @Value("${http.proxy.host}")
    private String httpProxyHost;
    @Value("${http.proxy.port}")
    private Integer httpProxyPort;

    @Value("${ff.tenant}")
    private UUID tenant;

    @Value("${ff.base-url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Value("${http.apply-proxy}")
    private boolean applyProxy;

    @Bean
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService,
            OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest> tokenResponseClient,
            @Qualifier("authorizationServerAuthorizationSuccessHandler") OAuth2AuthorizationSuccessHandler authorizationSuccessHandler,
            @Qualifier("authorizationServerAuthorizationFailureHandler") OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler authorizationFailureHandler) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials(r -> r.accessTokenResponseClient(
                        tokenResponseClient)).clientCredentials().build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager
                = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, oAuth2AuthorizedClientService);

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizationSuccessHandler(authorizationSuccessHandler);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizationFailureHandler(authorizationFailureHandler);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {

        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction
                        (authorizedClientManager);

        oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("b0cb877d-c10e-466d-b50e-c2883b1d5fed");

        ConnectionProvider provider =
                ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
                        .maxConnections(50)
                        .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                        .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                        .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                        .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
                        .build();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider);
        if (isApplyProxy()) {
            httpClient.proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                    .host(httpProxyHost)
                    .port(httpProxyPort));
        }

            ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            return WebClient.builder()
                    .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .clientConnector(connector)
                    .defaultHeader("X-TENANT-ID", tenant.toString())
                    .build();

    }

    @Bean("authorizationServerAuthorizationSuccessHandler")
    OAuth2AuthorizationSuccessHandler authorizationSuccessHandler(
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return (authorizedClient, principal, attributes) ->
                log.info("Authorization successful for clientRegistrationId={}",
                        authorizedClient.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId());
    }

    @Bean("authorizationServerAuthorizationFailureHandler")
    OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler authorizationFailureHandler(
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return new RemoveAuthorizedClientOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler(
                (clientRegistrationId, principal, attributes) -> {
                    log.info("Authorization failed for clientRegistrationId={}",
                            clientRegistrationId);
                    authorizedClientService.removeAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId,
                            principal.getName());
                });
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest> tokenResponseClient() {
        return new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
    }
}
```

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;


import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@ConfigurationProperties
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ffService {

    private final WebClient webClient;
   

    public ffMappedEntity getEntityDetails(UUID journeyId) {
        String journey = webClient.get()
                .uri("/ss/" + journeyId)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
        
    }

/*Other logic implementation*/  
}
```

Below are the error..

```
... 55 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.net.URL.(URL.java:541) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:635) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:315) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:455) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[oc-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:34) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar!/:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.util.AttributeKey$1.(AttributeKey.java:27) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar!/:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.(AttributeKey.java:27) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar!/:4.1.87.Final]
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:100) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.27.jar!/:1.0.27]
at reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$Builder.build(ConnectionProvider.java:497) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.27.jar!/:1.0.27]
at se.kyc.oc.service.coreService.config.OAuthWebClientConfig.webClient(OAuthWebClientConfig.java:94) ~[classes!/:na]
at se.kyc.oc.service.coreService.config.OAuthWebClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f063d2ac.CGLIB$webClient$4() ~[classes!/:na]
at se.kyc.oc.service.coreService.config.OAuthWebClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f063d2ac$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e97e63ab.invoke() ~[classes!/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
at se.kyc.oc.service.coreService.config.OAuthWebClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f063d2ac.webClient() ~[classes!/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
... 70 common frames omitted